# Getting A page can have only one server-side Form tag Error

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, radio-button

I have done my `MasterPage` and create a new `.aspx` page with this `MasterPage` . but whenever I try to add a `RadioButton` to the `.aspx` page it's generate to me this error:

> Control 'head_ctl00' of type 'RadioButton' must be placed inside a
>   form tag with runat=server.

and I have tried to add a form tag and this error came out !

> A page can have only one server-side Form tag.

I'm confused how I can solve this problem ! any idea ?

in case you need my `.aspx` page :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MySite.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Registration.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWebsite.Registration" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <form id="frm" runat="server">
        <asp:RadioButton runat="server"></asp:RadioButton>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add another radio button or are you referring to that one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have inserted your `RadioButton` inside the **`head`** placeholder that has not the form tag in your `MasterPage` file. You should place `RadioButton` in another `PlaceHolder` like **`MainContent`** or **`FeaturedContent`**. Also you don't need the form tag in your `ContentPages`, The form tag on the master page will be sufficient.